# Audio Equalizers (incl. Equalizer APO) not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

Auidio Equalizers are not working for me on windows 10, I have tried several equalizers, such as, Equalizer APO, Viper. What may be the problem and what can I do to solve it?

Also, audio extensions in Chrome are not working. The audio becomes silent. I don't think it is Chrome issue as there are no comments on extensions about that.

Currently I am using Windows 'High Defintion Audio Driver'. I also tried driver from manufacturer, but still same (Switched back to Windows driver cause driver on manufacturer site is more that 10 years old). I also tried installing generic audio drivers (RealTek, ASIO4all), but they don't work on my device.

Currently I am on Win 10 1909.

Comment: ASIO & APO are mutually exclusive afaik. APO works with your 'regular' Windows audio path, not with ASIO-capable software.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am talking about audio driver available at www.asio4all.org . Does APO don't use drivers to equalize 'audio'?

Comment: @Tetsujin they are mentioning that ASIO4All did not work, not that they use it in conjunction with APO. For APO to work, you first have to run the setup to select your audio device, reboot then it should be possible to use it, but in a recent windows build, APO stopped working for me too. So I think it is a problem with something changing in Windows 10. I did not look for an update from APO to get it fixed though, but they might be a new version of APO that works.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, I also followed the steps. I also tried troubleshooting options in different combinations, but APO didn't work.